# change master to cause 1364

Tags: mysql, replication, errors

```
ip addr|grep inet    
inet 192.168.8.47/24 brd 192.168.8.255 scope global ec1
inet 192.168.8.45/24 brd 192.168.8.255 scope global secondary ec1:1
```

I got like this

```
mysql> show slave status\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Queueing master event to the relay log
                  Master_Host: 192.168.8.47
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3310
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000126
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 82811044
               Relay_Log_File: c60-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 426371
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000125
```

the 8.47 ,will be remove on the master machine ,and then I do

```
on slave 
stop slave ;    
change master to master_host='192.168.8.45';    
start slave ;
```

and then I got error like

```
Last_Error: Error 'Field 'xxx' doesn't have a default value' on query.
```

what the database do ? when change master master_host only?

how to resolve this problem ,and the right way to change master (change master to master_host,user,root..etc)?

on the slave

```
mysql> select @@sql_mode;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| IGNORE_SPACE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What got that error?  The `CHANGE MASTER`?  Or some subsequent `INSERT`?  Do you have a column named "xxx"?

Comment: TKS for reply, got the error :  `Last_Errno: 1364`  ,the column exists!  I located the query and  execute the query ,just warnig without error,succeed !

Answer (score -1):

try with SET SQL_MODE = ''; or add this STRICT_TRANS_TABLES with existing data  modes

Comment: Answers that don't explain why they are correct, are not well received.  Take a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: tyr to set sql=''  when `start slave` but the error happened again ! Also try add TRICT_TRANS_TABLES